# Is there a Wordpress oauth2 client plugin that will work Laravel Passport as the oauth2 service provider?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have 2 sites, site A (Main Site) & site B (Wordpress woocommerce site). I would like my users to sign-in to site B using their Site A username and password. I have setup Oauth2 provider using Laravel passport that site A uses to authenticate users to site A. I'd like to do the same on site B. Is there an existing Wordpress plugin that will help me implement single sign on with my Oauth2 server that I've setup?

Answer (score -3):

WordPress plugins for oauth2

- Example for WordPress as a *server* or *identity provider* allowing WordPress users to authenticate on a 3rd party client, https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/
- Example for WordPress as a *client* replacing WordPress login a 3rd party identity provider, https://auth0.com/wordpress

Laravel core includes the Passport oauth2 server from thephpleague, which would server as a starting point for a custom integration.

- Server - https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server
- Client - https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client
- Example for *3rd party API authentication* without impact to WordPress auth, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/making-a-wordpress-plugin-that-uses-service-apis/

Please update and comment with alternatives not listed!